# yuicompressor and/or uglify-js does not work in PhpStorm

Tags: npm, phpstorm, yui-compressor

I have installed node package manager (npm) on my windows machine and then i ran the command "npm install less -g" and went on setting up the file watcher in PhpStorm for LESS. This worked very good. I also managed to get it to put the .css files in the css folder instead of in the less folder where I have my .less files.
My next step was to install yuicompressor so I ran the command "npm install yuicompressor -g". And then I set it up in PhpStorm by adding the yuicompressor for CSS, but it only creates empty .min.css files.

In the PhpStorm watcher settings I have set:

- Program: "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\yuicompressor.cmd"
- And ticked the box "Create output file from stdout"

I want to achieve this:
.less (project_root/less) -> .css (project_root/css) -> .min.css (project_root/css)

Is there any one else that has had the same problem, I can't seem to find any solution.

Btw, I also tried to install uglify-js, but with the same result, it only creates empy .min.js files.

Some extra info, my environment variables are as follows:

- PATH (User) = C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm
- Path (System) = C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: I do not know about nodejs version of YUICompressor -- original one works just fine: **1)** http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5481997 **2)** http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5482719 . Possibly the issue with "Create output file from stdout" -- maybe it is simply not needed??

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it got me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't know if it's feasible for you, but I have `less` -> `min.css` in one step using twitter's recess less compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the "Create output file from stdout" (from the yui CSS file watcher and left it checked on the LESS file watcher) and it seemed to work. But I had to link to the yuicompressor.cmd and not the .jar file as mentioned in the links from LazyOne. I also had to uncheck the "Immediate file synchronization" on the LESS file watcher but needed it to be checked on the yui CSS file watcher.

[image: The LESS file watcher]

[image: The yui CSS file watcher]

Seems like its very tricky to get it to go from "LESS -> CSS -> CSS compressed" with only saving the .less file when editing, but with this setup it finally worked.